# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (mesmo com aumento de memória)

Tags: java

Meu código está com esse erro. Porém já tentei:

1. Aumentar a memória nas configurações da VM:

> # custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options
>
> -Xms512m
>   -Xmx1024m
>   -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m
>   -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
>   -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
>   -ea
>   -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
>   -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

O método em que acontece esse estouro é esse:

```
public List<SearchByCity> getSearchesByCity(){
    List<SearchByCity> searches = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.asList(Estado.values()).forEach(uf -> {
        System.out.println(String.format("COLETANDO CIDADES EM %s", uf.getNome().toUpperCase()));
        try {
            List<String> cityNames = new ArrayList<>();
            HtmlPage page = WebClientFactory.getInstance().getPage(String.format(SEARCH_CITIES_URL, uf.toString().toLowerCase()));
            cityNames.addAll(Optional.ofNullable(page.<HtmlAnchor>getByXPath(CITYS_URLS_XPATH).stream()
                    .map(anc -> anc.getAttribute("title")).collect(Collectors.toList())).orElse(null));
            final JsonResponseByCity[] jsonResponseByCity = {null};
            if(Objects.nonNull(cityNames)){
                cityNames.forEach(city -> {
                    String cityName = removeAccents(city.replaceAll(" ", "-").toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", ""));
                    String url = String.format(SEARCH_BY_CITY_URL, uf.getNome(), cargoPolitico.getDescription(), cityName, uf.toString().toLowerCase(), cityName, cargoPolitico.getDescription());
                    try {
                        jsonResponseByCity[0] = ObjectMapperFactory.getInstance().readValue(WebClientFactory.getInstance().getPage(url).getWebResponse().getContentAsString(), JsonResponseByCity.class);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                    }
                    searches.add(new SearchByCity(uf.getNome().toUpperCase(), cityName, cargoPolitico, jsonResponseByCity[0]));
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    });
    if(searches.size() > 0)
        return searches;
    return null;
}
```

O estouro acontece na linha da atribuição de valor ao *jsonResponseByCity[0*].

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>
> at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)    at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
>     at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
>     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:190)   at
>   org.apache.commons.io.output.StringBuilderWriter.write(StringBuilderWriter.java:143)
>     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2370)   at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2348)    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2325)     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2273)     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1041)     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse.getContentAsString(WebResponse.java:246)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse.getContentAsString(WebResponse.java:191)
>     at
>   br.com.crawler.impl.eleicoes.page.SearchBuilder.lambda$null$2(SearchBuilder.java:71)

Comment: Não vou tentar analisar o código, até porque pode estar até em outro lugar, mas conserte o erro de programação. O problema não é o tamanho do *heap*.

Comment: Eu já revisei o código, mas a meu ver não tem erro de programação. Pelo que entendo o  json é atribuido a apenas um local na memória, já que estou definindo sua posição. Seria isso? Não compreendo esse erro

Comment: Se estamos a falar de interpretação json e é problema de memoria, sem olhar para o seu código (que não olhei), começaria por ver se não tem referencias circulares no seu json e/ou interpretação do mesmo. Isso pode ser motivo para ficar em loop criando objetos infinitamente.